# Run function if table only has one row

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table that has a filter pipe to filter out rows. Each row can be clicked to run an action.

Now the tricky part: I want to automaticly run the (click) event on a row (Or the function with access to the 'system' variable), if the table only contains a single row.

This is the html code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let system of systemData | tableFilter: systemSearchString" (click)="selectSystem(system)">
    <td>{{system.id}}</td>
    <td>{{system.number}}</td>
    <td>{{system.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

this is my pipe:

```
export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
   transform(list: TableItem[], value: string) {
      return value ? list.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) : list;
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do such a thing? Maybe somehow with checking if the `<tr>` is the only child of the parent?

Comment: What kind of function do you want to call ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do `systemData` filtering with  pipe as it doesn't give you any benefits(change detection won't be more performant with pipe, since new array will be returned on each `systemSearchString` change) and limits your control of data flow.

Instead, I would create filteredList variable (it can be array or Observable) and subscribe to `systemSearch` changes:

```
systemSearch.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''), // or some initial value if you have it
  debounceTime(100), // you can debounce input changes to reduce number of calculations
  map((query) => TableFilterPipe.transform(this.systemData, query)),
  tap((filteredList) => {
    if (filteredList.length === 1) {
      this.selectSystem(filteredList[0]);
    }
  })
)
```

If you want filteredList to be Observable, then just assign the stream above to it

```
this.filteredList$ = systemSearch.valueChanges.pipe(...)
```

In case of simple array, you should assign new filtered value in subscribe

```
systemSearch.valueChanges.pipe(...).subscribe((filtered) => this.filteredList = filtered);
```

I've used your pipe in stream and it should be modified to:

```
export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform { 
   static transform(list: TableItem[], value: string) {
      return value ? list.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())) : [...list];
   }

   transform(list: TableItem[], value: string) {
     TableFilterPipe.transform(list, value)
   }
}
```

or you can move this logic to some method in your component.

PS to improve change detection performance - use trackBy function for list

Comment: What type is the `systemSearch` you used in the code? Currently, my `systemSearchString` is a string that is binded to an input element with `ngModel`.

Comment: It's possible to implement with ngModel, but I would recommend to use [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control). Just define a form control and bind it to input, then you'll be able to subscribe for `valueChanges`